# SOLR error when trying to use '+' in a rang

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I'm trying to use SOLR rang to look for a value in a timestamp between `[NOW/DAY TO NOW/DAY+1DAY]` when I run it in the solr admin console it works fine but when I navigate to the link provided with the query I get 400 error 
`Cannot parse 'TIMESTAMP:[NOW/DAY TO NOW/DAY 1DAY]': Encountered \" <RANGE_GOOP> \"1DAY \"\" at line 1, column 37.\nWas expecting one of:\n    \"]\" ...\n    \"}\" ...\n    ",`
I noticed that the '+' was removed,even if it existed in the url .
thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try encoding the + char, so it looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core/select?q=[NOW/DAY TO NOW/DAY%2B1DAY]
```